# How can we guarantee high quality in the questions and answers on our site?

Tags: discussion, content-quality

One important aspect of every Stack Exchange site is guaranteeing that the questions and answers are high quality? **How should we address quality in our site?**

Answer (score 3):

As I said in [another answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/why-is-arduino-se-different-ee-se-redux), we should keep our **scope broad** and our **minds open**. But that doesn't mean we won't worry about quality. In summary, I think we should do appreciate questions that:

1. establishes a context (ie. why are you doing what you're doing)
2. has enough upfront research (the OP tried to solve the problem before coming to us)
3. shows us how the boards are connected (using schematics or those Arduino drawings linking pins with colored lines). We suggest that we aim at the same high standards as our Big Brother EE.SE site, as explained in those links:

   - [Good tools for drawing schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/good-tools-for-drawing-schematics)
   - [Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics)
4. what else?

We should also try and educate instead of censoring. If someone asks a poor quality question, editors should educate these users on how to ask better questions. The editors should try and improve the questions instead of quickly close them. So, we should avoid closing questions as much as possible. We should only close questions that are hopeless.

Comment: Good suggestions. To help people out, I think it would probably be useful to have some kind of documentation on how to create and upload schematics or other drawings.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield - That we already have - from our big brother EE site. See my updated anwser above.

Comment: For "what else," link to, in order of preference: 1) product pages that have links to schematics and data sheets, 2) directly to data sheets and schematics, and 3) product pages without such links.
     I've written ten or so answers in the last couple of days, and more often than not I've had to track down product information myself and, all to frequently, hope that what I'd found was actually for the right product.